# Spring Data Elasticsearch: Datas are stored in indexes despite "store" property is setted to false in @Field annotation

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, h2, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm making some tests with Spring Data Elasticsearch, Spring Boot, Spring Data Rest and an h2 Database (embedded).

I don't understand why the values are stored in the indexes despite I have this configuration:

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "computerindex", type="computers")
public class Computer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    @Field(type=FieldType.String, store=false) private String name; 
    @Field(type=FieldType.String, store=false) private String brand;

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(getNodeClient());
    }

    private static NodeClient getNodeClient() throws IOException {
        String pathHome = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new NodeBuilder();
        nodeBuilder
            .settings()
                .put("path.home", pathHome)
                .put("path.logs", pathHome+"/logs");
        return (NodeClient) nodeBuilder.clusterName("elasticsearch").local(true).node().client();
    }
}
```

Going to the url `http://localhost:8080/computers`, initially there is an **empty "_embedded" result** (as expected):

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "computers" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/computers"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

When I save a new "Computer", I have this result:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "computers" : [ {
      "name" : "pc",
      "brand" : "brand",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/AVZZwpMlqIneBcTGH3av"
        },
        "computer" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/AVZZwpMlqIneBcTGH3av"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/computers"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Now there is the interesting part.

If I stop the application and I restart it (without erase the indexes), since I have an embedded H2 database that runs and lives together with my application, I will expect that my "pc" is lost after that 
the previous session has been terminated.

The indexes are also configured **to not store any data**.

When I restart the application, I still have this result:

```
"computers" : [ {
  "name" : "pc",
  "brand" : "brand",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/AVZZwpMlqIneBcTGH3av"
    },
    "computer" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers/AVZZwpMlqIneBcTGH3av"
    }
  }
```

The only explanation could be that the values are *restored* from the indexes: in fact, if I delete the indexes before restarting the application, I have an empty database (as I expect).
But **I don't want to save the data in the indexes**, and **I don't want that the datas are pulled from the indexes**.
Furthermore, I have explicitely configured `store=false`, and **I didn't set** the `data(true)` property (like this):

```
return (NodeClient) nodeBuilder.clusterName("elasticsearch").local(true).data(true).node().client();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you're seeing is the `_source` of your document (which is stored by default), the `name` and `brand` fields are not stored (since `store=false`)

Comment: It's what I would think. But despite `store=false`, when I restart the application, the values are still recovered. This shouldn't be possibile.

Comment: `store=false` is **only** for fields, however, that won't modify the source document you're sending. That can only be done is you set `"_source": {"enabled": false}` in your mapping, which is a different thing.

Comment: I think I have understood what you are saying. Now the task is how to set the "_source" property with that value in the Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration.

Comment: Yes, indeed, not sure if that's possible though. But you can create the index outside of Spring Data if needed.